# Windows 10 disk partition missing

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive

lately, my disk has started to be utterly slow/unresponding, up to a point at which I can't even transfer data to USB and replace it.

Now, I've been trying to at least partially fix it in order to try and backup the data, but when I opened disk defragment window, I was surprised to see that my "E:/" disk partition is missing/being labled with some weird volume hash, instead of appearing normally just like the "F:/" partition which belongs to the same disk:

[image: Disk Defragment Screen]

So, I'm wondering now - this seems more like some type of malware than a physical failure. Data transfer from/to the "F:/" partition is working normally, "E:/" causes explorer to crash. They belong to the same physical drive. Any advice on how to solve this ?

Comment: Your disk seem to be dying or at least to have undergone a catastrophic crash. The partition table might be corrupted, but for better opinion we need a screenshot of the entire Device Management window.

Comment: Don't ever try to defragment a failing disk. That's a sure way to lose the whole lot. Don't run chkdisk either, that will do the same.

Comment: The screen shot looks like you have a volume that is not assigned to a drive letter.

Comment: Thanks all for the answer. @Tetsujin, unfortunately, too late for me :D

Already ran it and selected this:

"Would you like to force a dismount on this volume? (Y/N) y
Volume dismounted.  All opened handles to this volume are now invalid."

So at the moment, I'm waiting for it to finish, while it doesn't show in "My PC" anymore how much disk space is occupied/free. So.. =D possibly i've lost it already

Comment: OOps! Sorry, people always seem to go for that option without realising something like chkdisk's job is to fix the file system, it doesn't give a damn about your files & will sacrifice them all in order to complete its *actual* task.

Comment: @harrymc, I can upload a screen of the device management window, but only my SSD and HDD are listed there, nothing more than that. So I'm not sure if we're thinking about same window.

Comment: @Tetsujin, it's ok =D. I deeply knew it myself, that this could be the last nail in the coffin for this HDD =D. Not loving losing data, but it's not critical for me, so I guess I can live with it. Thanks a lot for even showing compassion here on superuser :D

Comment: @harrymc
Here are the physical devices present on my PC
https://i.postimg.cc/Kj11wtpJ/devices.png

No warnings when I open the HDD (WDC)


Also, chkdsk progress:
https://i.postimg.cc/PrrHXttn/chkdsk.png

Comment: I suggest using `ddrescue` to create an image of the drive, under Linux. Be aware that this will probably take multiple days, if not longer. // Please add new information [to your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1737545/edit).

Comment: This is not Disk Management - it's called in the Start menu "Create and format hard disk partitions". And never do `chkdsk /f` on a suspected failing disk! Change nothing!